# Finite dimensional representation of $SL_{2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let ($\pi , V$) be a finite dimensional representation of $SL_{2}$. Also, let $\alpha$ be highest weight vector. I want to show that for any $m>0$, then the following holds:

---

$\pi$($X$)($\pi$($Y$))$^{m}v=m$($\alpha - m +1$)($\pi$($Y$))$^{m-1}v$

---

How would presumably proof by induction work in practice?

Comment: What do $X$, $Y$, and $v$ stand for?

Comment: Advice: Do not assume that the notation used in your textbook is universally understood. The more advanced the topic the more likely it is that no universal standard exists. So, what are $X,Y,\alpha, v$? Mind you, (making educated guesses about the meaning of $X$ and $Y$) IMHO for the claim to make sense you probably want $v$ to be a highest weight vector and $\alpha$ to be the weight.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen hi, yes the $v$ stands for highest weight vector, and V is the vector space.